# Server error 500 Wagtail-admin

Tags: python, django, internal-server-error, wagtail

Currently I'm deploying a Wagtail project. It seems everything working fine so far but there is one issue I can't get rid of. When I'm trying to access the Wagtail admin url I get an internal server error since I changed my `settings` file `DEBUG` to `False`. That's not the case when I access django-admin. Generally the whole Site is working fine without errors. 
I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810855/wagtail-deployment-issue-keyerror-request-on-admin). But my 500.html template is not extending base.html and I'm also not using Compress. 
Any Ideas how I could solve this?

Comment: Look in your server logs. If you don't have any, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/

Comment: Have you tried running `python manage.py check --deploy` on your production server? It may give you a hint as to why things aren't working.

Comment: Post your server error logs to see what it's happening

Answer (score 4):

Try to run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Missing static files when `DEBUG = False` will cause 500 server error.

To see exactly what was the issue enable logging to a file by adding the following to the settings module (generally: settings.py):

```
#'''
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'your_site_name.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'MYAPP': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
#'''
```

This will log details about the error in 'your_site_name.log' in your project directory (you can also provide an absolute path).

When finished debugging just remove the first hash '#' from the code above to comment it and keep it for future debugging.

Comment: Did you have the same problem? And is that really a solution to this specific problem? Missing static files do not generally do not cause pages to return 500 errors. They'll just break styling, scripts and images.

Answer (score 2):

try looking in either your installed_apps or your urls.py.  you may be referencing something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you customized your admin try to remove or comment your customizing app from `INSTALLED_APPS`. Sometimes hooks for admin appear like this.